# Group rows without using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've build an SQL Fiddle for some data and to be more clear of what I want.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/076406/2

My query is

```
SELECT c1.ID 
,c1.Value Ian
,c2.Value Feb
,c3.Value Mar
,c4.Value Apr 
,c5.Value Mai 
,c6.Value Iun
,c7.Value Iul
,c8.Value Aug
,c9.Value Sept
,c10.Value Oct
,c11.Value Noe
,c12.Value Dec
 FROM A a
left outer join B as c1 on a.ID=c1.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 1
left outer join B as c2 on a.ID=c2.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 2
left outer join B as c3 on a.ID=c3.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 3
left outer join B as c4 on a.ID=c4.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 4
left outer join B as c5 on a.ID=c5.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 5
left outer join B as c6 on a.ID=c6.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 6
left outer join B as c7 on a.ID=c7.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 7
left outer join B as c8 on a.ID=c8.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 8
left outer join B as c9 on a.ID=c9.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 9
left outer join B as c10 on a.ID=c10.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 10
left outer join B as c11 on a.ID=c11.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 11
left outer join B as c12 on a.ID=c11.IDA and MONTH(a.ADate) = 12
WHERE YEAR(a.ADate) = 2014
```

So if you run this fiddle you will get data like this

```
ID   Ian   Feb  Mar  Apr ..
1    10   NULL NULL NULL
2    10   NULL NULL NULL 
3    10   NULL NULL NULL
4    10   NULL NULL NULL 
5    10   NULL NULL NULL
6    10   NULL NULL NULL 
7    10   NULL NULL NULL
8    10   NULL NULL NULL 
NULL NULL  9   NULL NULL
NULL NULL  9   NULL NULL 
NULL NULL  9   NULL NULL
NULL NULL  9   NULL NULL 
NULL NULL  9   NULL NULL
NULL NULL  9   NULL NULL 
NULL NULL  9   NULL NULL
NULL NULL  9   NULL NULL
```

and so on... I want do build a table like

```
ID   Ian   Feb  Mar  Apr ..
1    10     9   8    6
2    10     9   8    5
3    10     9   8    6
4    10     9   7    5 
5    10     9   7    6
6    10     9   8    5 
7    10     9   8    6
8    10     9   7    5
```

How can I achive this result? I'm clueless... any help would be nice. Also the query must run on an sql server 2005.

I will always have 8 values in table B  for each ID in table A, I would like somehow to group them together so my result table should have 8 rows and 13 columns. For each ID from table B a row and for each ID in table A a column + the ID column.

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: SQL Fiddle is nice and helpful, but it is *extra*. Place make sure to include the relevant details in the question as well.

Comment: Are you sure the ID column should be c1.ID, not A.ID? A bit of information about what this data is would help too. Now it's just a big bucket of abstract aliases and abstract numbers that make no sense. Is a.ID a month number? It looks like it.

Comment: I didn't want to load the question with all the building schema details, yes becouse each c1.ID has an unique name in an other table in my real DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   [1] as Ian, 
   [2] as Feb, 
   [3] as Mar, 
   [4] as Apr,
   [5] as Mai,
   [6] as Iun,
   [7] as Iul,
   [8] as Aug,
   [9] as Sept,
   [10] as Oct,
   [11] as Noe,
   [12] as Dec
FROM b
PIVOT
(
   SUM(Value) 
   FOR IDA IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
)  AS ResultTable
```

See [DEMO](http://rextester.com/SEGL43515)

*PIVOT and UNPIVOT are used against databases that are upgraded to SQL Server 2005 or later.*

Comment: Is PIVOT working in SQL 2005 ? If so, this is what I want, thank you for your help.

Comment: For my real db is not working properly but it's a start point and I will solve it.